# NSKeyedUnarchiver returns nil - Could not cast value of type 'MyProj.Meal' (0x105373f68) to 'MyProj.Meal' (0x11f5ee928)

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm trying to get the hang of archiving objects. I'm following Apple's example project for persistence here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html

Basically there's a Meal class that conforms to the NSCoding protocol. However when I run tests to archive/unarchive this Meal object, I get the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyProj.Meal' (0x105373f68) to 'MyProj.Meal' (0x11f5ee928)
```

Here's the code that produces the error; the error is on the third line:

```
let meal = Meal(name: "food", photo: nil, rating: 4)!
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: meal)
let unarchivedMeal = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! Meal

XCTAssertNotNil(unarchivedMeal)
```

And here's the meal class from Apple:

```
//
//  Meal.swift
//  FoodTracker
//
//  Created by Jane Appleseed on 11/10/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import os.log

class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {

//MARK: Properties

var name: String
var photo: UIImage?
var rating: Int

//MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")

//MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let photo = "photo"
    static let rating = "rating"
}

//MARK: Initialization

init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, rating: Int) {

    // The name must not be empty
    guard !name.isEmpty else {
        return nil
    }

    // The rating must be between 0 and 5 inclusively
    guard (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 5) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
    if name.isEmpty || rating < 0  {
        return nil
    }

    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.name = name
    self.photo = photo
    self.rating = rating

}

//MARK: NSCoding

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
    aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
    aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.rating)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
        debugPrint("Unable to decode the name for a Meal object.")
        return nil
    }

    // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage

    let rating = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.rating)

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating)

    }
}
```

Any ideas? This is really frustrating

Comment: Are you going to planning on updating to Swift 4 ? Because you can also use `Codable` conformance for `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject`

Comment: @nathan looks like 3.1: Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42); and im not sure i want to risk upgrading swift yet

Comment: Your code is working here

Comment: @nathan mmm strange; are you using unit tests to test the saving?

Comment: Yes. Try deleting DerivedData, uninstalling app

Comment: @nathan ok no luck still; maybe its a 3.1 bug. I'll try to find a workaround

Comment: @nathan ok it works but not in a unit test; I'm still curious why tho